# Where to put favicons in Django project?

Tags: django

I made a fav icon and ran it through a website to give me the different sizes and icons for different platforms.

In my base.html file I have:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static "apple-touch-icon.png" %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static "favicon-32x32.png" %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static "favicon-16x16.png" %}">
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static "site.webmanifest" %}">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static "safari-pinned-tab.svg" %}" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

And at the top of the base.html page I have `{% load static %}`

Rendering the page and pressing "view source" shows the links are good:
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/apple-touch-icon.png">`

All the icons are in `myapp/myapp/static/myapp` but it's giving me 404 errors. The static files in all my other apps work, but this being the coreapp did not previously have a `/static/myapp` directory.

My settings.py file located in `myapp/myapp/` has this in:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've obviously missed something in setting up the coreapp static files, or I'm placing them in the wrong directory, I dunno. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not include the sub-directory where you placed all your favicons. In case of my project I made '**icons**' folder inside '**static**' folder and I accessed them as:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{% static 'icons/apple-icon-57x57.png' %}">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{% static 'icons/apple-icon-60x60.png' %}">
........
```

So since you have placed your favicons inside '**myapp**' folder of '**static**' parent directory. Update above code as:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static "myapp/apple-touch-icon.png" %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static "myapp/favicon-32x32.png" %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static "myapp/favicon-16x16.png" %}">
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static "myapp/site.webmanifest" %}">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static "myapp/safari-pinned-tab.svg" %}" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: They're not in a sub directory, they are just in static. I have tried putting them in a subdirectory now, so:

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/myapp/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">`

is what is rendered, and:

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static "sunfire/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" %}">`

is what I have in the base.html file.
The files are in `myapp/myapp/static/myapp/icons/example.png`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

To my `settings.py` file. It wouldn't let me do this at first because I had the `STATIC_ROOT` set to the same value (ie. `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`, where django collects the static files) so I guess I just have to choose a new static root.